# Wrong month printed on last day of August

Tags: php

I had this bug yesterday (August 31st) where the following printed out...

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Helsinki');
$calendar_month_name = DateTime::createFromFormat('m', 9, $timezone)->format('F');

echo $calendar_month_name; // returns October

echo date('M'); // returns August
```

However, when the date changed to the 1st September, `$calendar_month_name` corrected itself.

Anyone know why this was? Thanks.

**Edit** I've turned my calendar back to be on the 31 Aug again, which is why `echo date('M');` returns August.

**Edit 2** Here is an example using `date()`

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Helsinki');
echo date('F', mktime(0,0,0,9)); // returns October
```

Comment: What is your timezone?

Comment: Europe/Helsinki (EEST)

Comment: try `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Helsinki');` and check if they are the same. the `date(..)` function takes the timezone of your server into account.

Comment: Setting `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Helsinki')` then calling `$calendar_month_name = DateTime::createFromFormat('m', 9)->format('F');` yields the same result. I think it's something to do with the PHP’s Global TimeZone via php.ini. I'll try and set that then get back.

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set` will affect the call to `date` function

Comment: Ah, I see. I was trying to use the DateTime class though.

Comment: Even for date(), the following still returns October... `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Helsinki'); 
echo date('F', mktime(0,0,0,9));
`

Comment: Which version of PHP you use? And what OS you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu), 
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19 (cli), Zend Engine v2.5.0, Zend OPcache v7.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

In one line you are asking the name of the month 9 which is September.
On the last line you are asking the short name of the current month.

I think that this is what you intend, isn't?

```
$calendar_month_name = DateTime::createFromFormat('m', date('m'),$timezone)->format('F');
```

Cheers!

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, but it wasn't. The short month was just to test the current month. I'm really getting October returned for the 9th month in the earlier example.

Comment: Please fix your formatting. 4 spaces indent make 2-newlines-separated paragraph displayed as code. Best regards.

Comment: Done! Tks for the tip.